# Different behaviour when running the same app version from Android Studio than when running from Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

This is the strangest question I will ever ask: I'm getting different behaviour for an Android App I developed when running from Android Studio than when running the released version from Google Play.

I know this sound crazy, but is is true.

Example:

- I run version X from Android Studio on any cell phone or emulator (I tryied in maybe 10 different)
- A Picasso loaded image is shown to perfection, loaded from Drawable
- A JSON string that is sent to a WS is created and sent to the server
- Now I build version X and release to Google Play, wait for release and install in all same phisical devices (no emulators here)
- The picasso image is not shown
- The JSON string is not created and sent as empty "{}" to the server

This is absolute madness.

Android Studio is up to date. I try devices and emulators from Android 6 up to 9. LogCat shows no errors or warnings. I have added tons of debug lines but nothing helps. Gradle is up to date. MinSDK is 23, TargetSDK is 29.

What can it be? Has anyone ever faced a situation like this one before?

This app was in production and working fine until two weeks ago when all this started.

Comment: Curious: which result do you get if you manually send the APK to the device and install it from the file manager?

Comment: Thanks Ryan M for the suggestion, will try and let you know.

Comment: Check your proguard rules

Comment: Thanks Mouaad Abdelghafour AITALI, proguard-rules.pro is empty. Is there any lines in particular you suggest adding?

Comment: Easy way to fix them is mark minifyEnabled to false when build release again. About Json root cause is Android auto encode Gson Model, it means live version not work properly, you should add ignore rules to proguard file with Gson Model.

Comment: Thanks Công Hải, that sounds promissing. I have just uploaded the new version to Google Play, in a couple of hours I'll tell the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Công Hải was rigth.

The problem was the minify=true. Turning it to false solved the issue.

Will work on proguard rules in order to be able to keep the minify enabled.

Still I wonder why it stopped working from one version to another.

Thanks Công Hải!